# C# connection class data sources

Tags: c#, class, connection, datasource

How do I modify this data source from this line

```
`String constr = (@"Data source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; initial catalog=DataHRD; integrated security=true;");`
```

`(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB ==> C:\Users\SONY\Desktop\asda\asd\MainMenu\DataHRD.mdf`

or different directory out of localdb

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, and you just want to build or change your connection string in code, the you could just use the [SqlConnectionStringBuilder Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Provides a simple way to create and manage the contents of connection
>   strings used by the SqlConnection class.

**Example**

```
String constr = (@"Data source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; initial catalog=DataHRD; integrated security=true;");

// Create a new SqlConnectionStringBuilder and
// initialize it with a few name/value pairs.
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder =
   new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(constr);


// Now that the connection string has been parsed,
// you can work with individual items.
builder["Data Source"] = @"C:\Users\SONY\Desktop\asda\asd\MainMenu\DataHRD.mdf"

// or anything else
builder.Password = "new@1Password";
builder.AsynchronousProcessing = true;

// You can refer to connection keys using strings, 
// as well. When you use this technique (the default
// Item property in Visual Basic, or the indexer in C#),
// you can specify any synonym for the connection string key
// name.
builder["Server"] = ".";
builder["Connect Timeout"] = 1000;
builder["Trusted_Connection"] = true;
```

***Disclaimer***, this is just an example, you will have change this to your needs

Comment: how about login failed?
im using visual studio 2017

Comment: @Necrodor21Sa if the login failed you will need to check your connection string is correct and working

Answer (score 0):

```
//first add your Database to SQL-SERVER
//then use this way
//if in Server use SSPI 

string constr = (@"Data Source=.\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=DataHRD;Integrated Security=SSPI");
```